# I forgot my server name for SQL server 2012 windows authentication

Tags: database, authentication, sql-server-2012, windows-authentication

I installed SQL Server 2012, I forgot what is server name for windows authentication. I am not able to login, I dont know how to find server name. Please help.[SQL LOGIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87Ze.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Here's two options...

1. Logon to the server you installed this instance on, open SSMS and use `localhost` as the Server Name. Then you can right click on the server and find out all of the details about it.
2. Browse to it by clicking the drop down arrow and selecting  **IF** you enabled the SQL Browser service during installation. The installer would have recommended you not enable this by default I believe.